# Is an exact functor half exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

I am working with $R$-modules, where $R$ i a commutative ring

If $F$ is an additive covariant exact functor between $_RMod$ and $_SMod$, is the following proposition true? I like references

$M  \to N \to L $ is exact $\Rightarrow$ $FM \to FN \to FL$ is exact

*For me, exact functors preserve short exact sequences.

Comment: Are you sure you want the direction $\Leftarrow$ as well?

Comment: No, it is not well